# Error using sign.sign() in Node.js crypto, bad decrypt

Tags: node.js, cryptography, sign

New to node.js and I got error using sign() in crypto.Please help!

I created sign 
using `const sign = crypto.createSign('sha256');` and then tried to sign with `var signature = sign.sign(key,'hex');` the key is generated using

```
const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
  modulusLength: 2048,
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'spki',
    format: 'pem'
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs8',
    format: 'pem',
    cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
    passphrase: 'top secret'
  }
});

const key = privateKey;
const seller_public_key = publicKey
```

what I tried to sign is an JSON object that are converted to string using `jsonData = JSON.stringify(menu);return signData(jsonData);`

```js
function signData(plaintext){
  sign.update(plaintext);
  sign.end();
  var signature = sign.sign(key,'hex');
  return signature;
}
```

I got error message:

```
internal/crypto/sig.js:80
  var ret = this._handle.sign(key, passphrase, rsaPadding, pssSaltLength);
                         ^

Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

And I've seen some people talk about key format, my key format indeed starts with `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`, end with `-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your private key is encrypted, you should pass the passphrase in the `sign` call:

```
sign.sign({ key, passphrase: 'top secret' }, 'hex');
```

> The privateKey argument can be an object or a string. If privateKey is
> a string, it is treated as a raw key with no passphrase. If privateKey
> is an object, it must contain one or more of the following properties:
>
> - key:  - PEM encoded private key (required)
> - passphrase:  - passphrase for the private key
> - ...

Reference: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_sign_sign_privatekey_outputencoding

Comment: thanks @anthonku! how could I specify its string and leave the passphrase out?

Comment: Hi @matt, in order to create a signature without supplying a passphrase, the key needs to be unencrypted. You can generate the key without a passphrase by omitting `cipher` and `passphrase` options.